# Getting occuring appointment with SFCalendar flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Im trying make a calendar app and Im thinking of displaying the appointment that is happening right now from the appointment data to the home page. And I dont know how to get that appointment. Anyone could help me out with this? Thanks in advance.

I tried to use a loop which check which appointment start and end time is within the current time but I think that would make a bad performance for a device. And this is also not working with recurring appointment.

```
Future addEvent() async {
    isLoaded = false;
    var userdoc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .get();

    //dev.log("sdsd");

    if (userdoc.exists) {
      Map<String, dynamic> userdata = userdoc.data()!;

      //log("message");

      idlist = userdata['joined'];

      ////log(friendsList.toString());
      //friendsList = (value.data() as dynamic)["friends"];

      for (var i = 0; i < idlist.length; i++) {
        dev.log(idlist[i]);
        var evnetref = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("schedules")
            .doc(idlist[i])
            .get();
        eventlist = evnetref['events'];
        email = evnetref["owner"];
        if (eventlist.isNotEmpty) {
          for (var e = 0; e < eventlist.length; e++) {
            Map<String, dynamic> scheduledata = eventlist[e];
            if (exit != true) {
              if (evnetref.exists) {
                //Map<String, dynamic> scheduledata = shareddoc.data()!;

                DateTime to = scheduledata["to"].toDate();
                DateTime from = scheduledata["from"].toDate();
                dev.log(to.toString());
                //startCountdown();
                if (to.isAfter(DateTime.now())) {
                  if (from.isBefore(DateTime.now()) ||
                      from.isAtSameMomentAs(DateTime.now())) {
                    LocalNotifications.showSimpleNotification(
                        title: "You've got an Appointment",
                        body:
                            "You've got an appointment ${scheduledata["title"]} from ${fromtime.hour.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${fromtime.minute.toString().padLeft(2, '0')} to ${totime.hour.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${totime.minute.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
                        payload: "");
                    startCountdown(((to.millisecondsSinceEpoch -
                                DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch) /
                            1000)
                        .ceil());
                    setState(() {
                      dev.log(((to.millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString())));
                      dev.log(((to.millisecondsSinceEpoch -
                                  DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch) /
                              1000)
                          .toString());
                      name = scheduledata["title"];
                      email = evnetref["owner"];
                      fromtime =
                          TimeOfDay(hour: from.hour, minute: from.minute);
                      totime = TimeOfDay(hour: to.hour, minute: to.minute);
                      isLoaded = true;
                    });
                  } else {
                    //dev.log("Next : " + scheduledata["title"]);
                    setState(() {
                      name = "Next : " + scheduledata["title"];
                      fromtime =
                          TimeOfDay(hour: from.hour, minute: from.minute);
                      totime = TimeOfDay(hour: to.hour, minute: to.minute);
                      //email = eventref["owner"];
                      note = scheduledata["description"];
                      isLoaded = true;
                      //dev.log('onEnd2');
                      CountdownTimer(
                        endTime: from.millisecondsSinceEpoch,
                        onEnd: addEvent,
                      );
                      exit = true;
                    });
                  }
                } else {
                  setState(() {
                    //dev.log('onEnd');
                    fromtime = TimeOfDay(hour: 0, minute: 0);
                    totime = TimeOfDay(hour: 0, minute: 0);
                    email = "@dev";
                    note = "-";
                    isLoaded = true;
                    name = "No Current Event";
                    //exit = false;
                  });
                }
              } else {
                setState(() {
                  //dev.log('onEnd');
                  fromtime = TimeOfDay(hour: 0, minute: 0);
                  totime = TimeOfDay(hour: 0, minute: 0);
                  email = "@dev";
                  note = "-";
                  isLoaded = true;
                  name = "No Current Event";
                  //exit = false;
                });
              }
            } else {
              return;
            }
          }
        } else {
          setState(() {
            //dev.log('onEnd');
            fromtime = TimeOfDay(hour: 0, minute: 0);
            totime = TimeOfDay(hour: 0, minute: 0);
            email = "@dev";
            note = "-";
            isLoaded = true;
            name = "No Current Event";
            //exit = false;
          });
        }
      }
      setState(() {
        isLoaded = true;
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.